# Certification Maintenance Exam for DEV 401 folks

Tags: certification

I have not received any emails from Salesforce asking to complete the maintenance exam to maintain my 401 credentials.

Is it because they have introduced the two new certifications for Developers (SCPD 1 & 2) and as such maintenance exams are no longer needed for folks with 401 credentials only ?

Answer (score 1):

Per http://certification.salesforce.com/schedules, Winter '16 Release Exams will be available on November 11th.

Based on communications to the Partner Community, though I have no one example I can cite on this, I would expect that until 401 is fully retired, you will still need to take your release exams as planned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I recall receiving notification, either. But if you log into webassessor, you should find the Winter 16 release exams available for any certifications you have.

At least, I do when I login, not having yet completed it.

[image]